# Convert 1 × CN matrix to C × N matrix

Tags: matrix, stata

What's the most efficient way to convert 1 × CN matrix to C × N matrix?

Here is the problem I have been facing.

1. I have been using micro-household data in Pakistan,and estimated elasticity by using AIDS model and `nlcom` command.

   ```
    nlsur quaids @ w1 w2 w3 w4 w5 w6 w7 lnp1-lnp8 lnm [pw=weight], /* 
        */ ifgnls nequations(7) /*
        */ param(a1 a2 a3 a4 a5 a6 a7 b1 b2 b3 b4 b5 b6 b7 g11 g12 g13 g14 g15 g16 g17 g22 g23 g24 g25 g26 g27 g33 g34 g35 g36 g37 g44 g45 g46 g47 g55 g56 g57 g66 g67 g77 l1 l2 l3 l4 l5 l6 l7) nolog

    nlcom (eh11:[g11]_cons/m_w1 + m_w1 - 1)/*
        ..........
        */ (eh77:[g77]_cons/m_w7 + m_w7 - 1)
   ```
2. Then I got the Hicksian elasticity, which is 1 × 49 matrix.

   ```
   matrix list r(b)
   ```
3. I want to estimate compensating variation by using Hicksian elasticity when the price of goods rises, so I have to convert the elasticity matrix from 1 × 49 to 7 × 7, but I cannot make this matrix though trying many ways.

---

UPDATE:

By following previous advice, I got the result as below.

---

`matrix list Es`

Es[8,8]

```
      c1        c2        c3         c4         c5         c6         c7         c8
```

r1  -.55723312  .17792396   .07480918   .08014676   -.14777629  .06792643   .14629625  .15790682

r2   .37012189  -.53367971  -.01898065  .01182084   .10687796   -.01585994  -.07652818 .15622777

r3   .43624245  -.05320763  -.62772824  .10168586   -.2441294   .18205766   -.04611322 .25128797

r4    .1708841  .01211585   .03717947   -.36135548  .09168136   .03541119   .02722708  .12727678

r5  -.14553177  .05059771   -.04122874  .04234659   -.19625015  .1456979    .01555162  .12692767

r6    .2928915  -.0328745   .13461825   .07161317   .63792299   -1.2204229  .0387352   .21100258

r7   .20829112  -.05237797  -.01125875  .01818122   .0224833    .01279014  -.24563738  .10818032

r8   .11555958  .05496079   .03152381   -.00451132  .09572484   .01315618   .02442979     -.33084368`

---

Then after I want to generate Compensating Variables of each household (CV_h) as below,
but I cannot program the equation as below, which is same as the link.(page 9 equation5)
http://www.nber.org/papers/w8564.pdf

`⊿ln(CV_h) = Σ(w'i'_h * ⊿ln(p'i'_h)) + 0.5ΣΣ(w'i'_h * Es'i''j' * ⊿ln(p'i'_h) * ⊿ln(p'j'_h))`

The variables, except for Es'i''j' which is formatted following your advice, are already given.

Comment: Personal stuff (thanks, signatures, etc.) is out of place in questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is using Mata:

```
clear
set more off

// example matrix
matrix E = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
matrix list E

// change shape
mata:
Em = st_matrix("E") // take matrix to Mata
Em = colshape(Em,3) // change shape
st_matrix("Es", Em) // take result to Stata
end

// list in Stata
matrix list Es
```

See `help mata`, `help mata colshape`, and `help [M-4] manipulation`.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, your comment was perfect.
I added one more question, and I would like you to solve this problem also.

Sorry for my question again.

Kento

Comment: You're welcome. If the answer solves the initial problem you posted, then you can [give closure the Stack Overflow way](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Please do not insert a new, "unrelated", question within your original post. You can try posting it as a different question since, in programming terms, it has nothing to do with the original. That said, if you provide a new post by just copying/pasting what you have here, I predict it will be of little interest to people trying to help.  It may even be deemed off-topic. Help us help you and read carefully: http://stackoverflow.com/help, on asking good questions.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, and sorry for that I was not familiar with this site.

I accepted your advice, and post the question as a different one the link below.


[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27717408/estimating-compensating-variables-by-using-estimated-price-elasticity]